# While using min_element in c++ the second range is not included

Tags: c++

```
min_element(vec.begin()+3,vec.begin()+5)
```

Here `vec.begin+3` is include but  `vec.begin+5` is not inclusive how do I make it inclusive?

Comment: Please show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, the end of a range in C++ is never an included element (otherwise it would be difficult to represent an empty range).  To include `vec.begin()+5` specify the end of the range as `vec.begin()+6`.

Comment: What if vec.begin()+5 is the last element

Comment: Then `vec.begin()+6` represents the end of the container. The end iterator does not refer to an element of a container - you can think of it as just past the last element. It is never valid to dereference an end iterator, but it is valid to compare the end iterator to another iterator to the same container.

Answer (score 7):

> `min_element(vec.begin()+3,vec.begin()+5)`
>
> Here `vec.begin+3` and `vec.begin+5` are not inclusive how do i make them inclusive?

That's not correct.

`vec.begin()+3` is inclusive.

To make `vec.begin()+5` inclusive, use `vec.begin()+6` as the second argument.

```
min_element(vec.begin()+3, vec.begin()+6)
```

Comment: What if vec.begin()+5 is the last element

Comment: @Rahulmalawadkar, that's ok. It will be the same as using `vec.end()`.